# Eclipse warns about error when using Spring AOP

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-tool-suite

I am using Eclipse STS 3.6.4 (based on Eclipse Luna 4.4.2), and I am building an app using Spring Boot and Spring AOP.

My code looks like this:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* test.Service.handle(..))")
public void serviceOperation() {
}

@Pointcut("serviceOperation() && args(snapshot)")
public void snapshotServiceOperation(Snapshot snapshot) {
}

@AfterReturning("snapshotServiceOperation(snapshot)")
public synchronized void logExecution(Snapshot snapshot) {
    logger.info("Look, it's a {}", snapshot);
}
```

This works fine, but Eclipse is reporting the following error:

```
Spring AOP Problem (2 items):
 - Exception from reflection '8810'
 - Pointcut is malformed: warning no match for this type name: snapshot [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
```

It is annoying because the program works fine, but Eclipse highlights the error and asks "Are you sure you want to run a program with errors?" every time I run it.

Comment: Is your pointcut expression correct? Can you post your <aop:config> tag, plz?

Comment: @BurakKeceli there isn't anything else, I am not using XML configuration files. The pointcut expressions are all above.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find the reason for it? For the moment I have just turned of the errors :)